# Multiple RestTemplate calls for each Id in a List

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-resttemplate

I need to make multiple `RestTemplate` calls for each of the `Id` in a `List<Ids>`. What is the best way to perform this?

I have used `parallelStream()`. Below code snippet is a similar scenario.

```
List<Integers> employeeIds;
employeeIds.parallelStream().
.map(empId -> employeeService.fetchEmployeedetails(empId))
.collect(Collectos.toList());
```

`employeeService.fetchEmployeedetails` is a kind of `restCall` which will fetch all the `employeeDetails`.

Is there any other way to tune the performance?

Comment: how do you think that this can be optimized? we don't know anything about the API, maybe it allows a batch result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.parallelStream()` does not guarantee multi threading since it will create only threads equals to number of cores you have. To really enforce multiple threads doing this simultaneously, you need to use .parallelStream() with `ForkJoinPool`.

##### High Performance using ForkJoinPool

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList();
ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(50);
try {
    forkJoinPool.submit(() -> employeeIds.parallelStream().forEach(empId -> {
         Employee em = employeeService.fetchEmployeedetails(empId);
         synchronized(employees) {
              employees.add(em);
         }
    })).get();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new BusinessRuleException(ErrorCodeEnum.E002501.value(), e.getMessage());
} finally {
    if (forkJoinPool != null) {
        forkJoinPool.shutdown(); // always remember to shutdown the pool
    }
}
```

This will ensure that parallelStream() **creates max 50 threads** instead of depending on number of cores of your system. Make sure you do not forget to `shutdown()` of the pool in finally block. and also do not forget `.get();` which triggers execution of the thread.

ArrayList is not thread-safe to modify but `synchronized()` will provide that safety. Since the adding to the list is quite minor operation, it will not hold the thread long either.

You will see tremendous performance improvement with this approach.

##### How to choose optimal number for threads

Too many threads would cause context switch and slow down the process. Too less threads keep the system underutilized. The optimum thread count is often around 10 times the number of cores you have. Also depends on time you are going to spend within the thread. I generally pass an environment variable, so that i can tune the number 50 when I want. But I have reached 50 after quite a bit of experiment on a quad core instance that we have.

```
    @Value("#{systemEnvironment['parallelism'] ?: 50}")
    protected int parallelism;
```

and then use `ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(getParallelism());`